# How to sign JWT?

Tags: ruby, authentication, oauth, sinatra, jwt

I'm trying to secure a Sinatra API.

I'm using `ruby-jwt` to create the JWT, but I don't know exactly what to sign it with.

I'm trying to use the user's BCrypt `password_digest`, but every time `password_digest` is called it changes, making the signature invalid when I go to verify it.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson I commented on your answer but I never got an answer to that. It helped me though yes. I'll mark it but please answer.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson I had up voted the answer but not accepted it.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson I just saw it now thanks. It's a good answer. I couldn't find anything online about what a good approach would be for this and it's really quite simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any kind of application secret key, not a user's bcrypt password digest.

For example, use the dot env gem and a .env file, with an entry such as:

```
JWT_KEY=YOURSIGNINGKEYGOESHERE
```

I personally generate a key by using a simple random hex string:

```
SecureRandom.hex(64)
```

The hex string contains just 0-9 and a-f, so the string is URL safe.

Comment: Okay but what should I use to generate the actual key? I'm thinking something like `Base64.encode64(SecureRandom.random_bytes(128))`. Is that okay? Should it be longer or different?

Answer (score 4):

For RS256 public and private key strategy you can use Ruby OpenSSL lib:

Generating keys:

```
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 2048

open 'private_key.pem', 'w' do |io| io.write key.to_pem end
open 'public_key.pem', 'w' do |io| io.write key.public_key.to_pem end
```

Load key from .pem file to sign token:

```
priv_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read 'private_key.pem'
token = JWT.encode payload, priv_key, 'RS256'
```

Load key from .pem file to Verify token(Create a middleware for this):

```
      begin
        # env.fetch gets http header
        bearer = env.fetch('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION').slice(7..-1)
        pub_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read 'public_key.pem'
        payload = JWT.decode bearer, pub_key, true, { algorithm: 'RS256'}
        
        # access your payload here
  
        @app.call env

      rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature
        [403, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' }, ['The token has expired.']]
      rescue JWT::DecodeError
        [401, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' }, ['A token must be passed.']]
      rescue JWT::InvalidIssuerError
        [403, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' }, ['The token does not have a valid issuer.']]
      rescue JWT::InvalidIatError
        [403, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' }, ['The token does not have a valid "issued at" time.']]
      end
```

To use RSA key in your `.env` instead of loading a file, you will need to use `gem 'dotenv'` and import the key as a single line variable with the use of newline `'\n'`. check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457787/how-to-export-a-multi-line-environment-variable-in-bash-terminal-e-g-rsa-privat/61978397#61978397) on how to do it. example:

```
PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nmineminemineminemine\nmineminemineminemine\nmineminemine...\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
```

as an `.env` `PUBLIC_KEY` variable, loading the key will change to this:

```
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new ENV['PUBLIC_KEY']
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_(cryptography)), a secret key used in cryptography is basically just that, a key to open the lock. The key should be consistent and reliable, but not easy to duplicate, just like a key you would use on your home.

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28841267/5555492), secret keys should be randomly-generated. However, you still want the key to be retained for use across the application. By using the password digest from bcrypt, you are actually using a hashed key that was derived from a base secret key (the password). Because the hash is random, this is not a reliable secret key to use, as you stated.

The previous answer using `SecureRandom.hex(64)` is a great way to create an initial base application key. However, in a production system, you should be taking this in as a configuration variable and storing it for consistent use across multiple runs of your application (for example following a server reboot, you should not invalidate all of your user's JWTs) or across multiple distributed servers. [This article](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/20/a-better-way-to-manage-the-rails-secret-token/) gives an example of pulling in the secret key from an environment variable for rails.