# How to Export a Multi-line Environment Variable in Bash/Terminal e.g: RSA Private Key

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, multiline, private-key

One of our Apps [`github-backup`](https://github.com/dwyl/github-backup) requires the use of an RSA Private Key as an Environment Variable.

Simply attempting to export the key it in the terminal e.g:
`text
export PRIVATE_KEY=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA04up8hoqzS1+
...
l48DlnUtMdMrWvBlRFPzU+hU9wDhb3F0CATQdvYo2mhzyUs8B1ZSQz2Vy==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Does not work ... because of the line breaks.

I did a bit of googling but did not find a workable solution ... 
e.g: [How to set multiline RSA private key environment variable for AWS Elastic Beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082918/how-to-sett-multiline-rsa-private-key-environment-variable-for-aws-elastic-beans)

[image]

Error:

`-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----': not a valid identifier`

followed the instructions in: 
http://blog.vawter.com/2016/02/10/Create-an-Environment-Variable-from-a-Private-Key

Created a file called `keytoenvar.sh` with the following lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
file=$2
name=$1
export $name="$(awk 'BEGIN{}{out=out$0"\n"}END{print out}' $file| sed 's/\n$//')"
```

[image]
then ran the following command:

```
source keytoenvar.sh PRIVATE_KEY ./gitbu.2018-03-23.private-key.pem
```

That *works* but it seems like a "*long-winded*" approach ...

Does anyone know of a *simpler* way of doing this? 
(*I'm hoping for a "**beginner friendly**" solution without too many "steps"...*)

Comment: Your .sh script had a problem: you were trying to `export $var` (by reference/value) but should `export var` (by name) instead. Anyway, the answer is simple: `bash` allows multiline string literals, as long as they are quoted. Use either single or double quotes.

Comment: @MarkHu Your approach is not working.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what I'm looking at, you've published a private key on Stack Overflow for the world to see. It's been a year, but if this key is still active, you should change it.

Comment: @rp.beltran the key is not long enough to be a valid RSA private key. but thanks for your concern. :-)

Comment: Good point, my bad

Answer (score 125, accepted):

**export the key**

```
export PRIVATE_KEY=`cat ./gitbu.2018-03-23.private-key.pem`
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$PRIVATE_KEY";
```

**Note:** the `"` in the `echo` above are needed - otherwise the new lines will be converted to spaces!

If you want to save the key to a `.env` file with the rest of your environment variables, all you needed to do is "wrap" the private key string in *single quotes* in the `.env` file ... e.g: `sh exports HELLO_WORLD='-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA04up8hoqzS1+APIB0RhjXyObwHQnOzhAk5Bd7mhkSbPkyhP1 ... iWlX9HNavcydATJc1f0DpzF0u4zY8PY24RVoW8vk+bJANPp1o2IAkeajCaF3w9nf q/SyqAWVmvwYuIhDiHDaV2A== -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'` 
So the following command will work:

```
echo "export PRIVATE_KEY='`cat ./gitbu.2018-03-23.private-key.pem`'" >> .env
```

Followed by:

```
source .env
```

Now the key will be in your .env file and whenever you source .env it will be exported.

Comment: As noted in this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271334/292408, the `echo $PRIVATE_KEY` sometimes strips all the newlines when showing output. I think it depends on the shell of maybe version or echo. But the example would be better & more accurate if wrapped with double quotes.

Comment: Also of note that I just realized, `env` always shows the variables correctly, with newlines.

Comment: when i try access my key from .env file its only returning the first line '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'

Comment: I m only getting last line of the key file in this case

Comment: I'm using a .env file with a project in Glitch, and wrapping the key in single quotes was the only solution that worked for me...I had been searching for awhile so thanks!!

Comment: Evaluating a variable in .env ins not an option for most applications. Imagine an encrypted private keys in Kubernetes service for example. 

As proposed in the end of this thread: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-environment-variables/issues/17 the best option is to encode the key with a base64 and decode it when accessing it.

Answer (score 52):

If you want to export direct value (not from *.pem) then use `"` after equals sign. The terminal will let you finish with another `"`.

```
export PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA04up8hoqzS1+
...
l48DlnUtMdMrWvBlRFPzU+hU9wDhb3F0CATQdvYo2mhzyUs8B1ZSQz2Vy==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

Comment: I have tried the same but instead of reading the full key it is reading it as ```"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----```

Comment: @WasifAli Did u really put `"` after `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`?

Comment: Yes I have tried this, it didn't work, so what worked for me was to replace all the new lines with '\n' characters.

Answer (score 26):

**NOTE**: For me to get the output to work correctly, I had to wrap the environment variable in double quotes. Otherwise it replaced newlines with spaces.

In:

```
export PRIVATE_KEY=$(cat ./gitbu.2018-03-23.private-key.pem)
```

Out:

```
echo "$PRIVATE_KEY"
```

Comment: DAMN!!! This is great, I kept checking a variable without the quotes and kept getting 1 line (`echo $TEST | wc --lines`). And was going crazy!!! Thanks for suggesting this, very helpful in determining it actually did have all the lines.

Comment: Also of note that I just realized, `env` always shows the variables correctly, with newlines.

Answer (score 17):

What I wanted is one and only one executable shell script containing it all, and not 1 script and 1 `.pem` file and then doing some gymnastics in between, like what I am seeing in the existing answers so far.

To achieve this unification, all that is needed is the following. Preparation phase:

```
cat id_rsa | base64 -w0
# assign the converted 1-liner string wrap in single quote into a shell variable, for example
pk='xxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzzzzz......'
```

The rest is walk-in-the park. To ssh using variable `pk` you will convert back the 1-liner string into its original posture and write to a temporary file.

```
t=$(mktemp ~/temp.XXXXXXXXXX)
printf $pk | base64 --decode > $t
ssh -i $t smeagol@192.143.69.69
```

To clean-up the temporary file when your shell script exits, add a shell `trap` handler:

```
trap cleanup 1 2 3 6
cleanup () {
    rm -f $t
}
```

To improve security, notice the use of `mktemp ~/temp.XXXXXXXXXX` so the temporary file is written somewhere within your `$HOME` folder where only you can read, rather than in a system wide `/tmp` folder where other users in the same server can read.

Comment: base64 encoding the key also turned out to be the best solution for me

Comment: `cat id_rsa | base64 -w0` This is the life saver. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Adding a RSA key to an `.env` file.

Step 1.

```
echo "PRIVATE_KEY=\"`sed -E 's/$/\\\n/g' my_rsa_2048_priv.pem`\"" >> .env
```

Your key in the `.env` file will look something like this:

```
PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
dasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadasdasdadasa\n
huehuauhhuauhahuauhauahuauhehuehuauheuhahue\n
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

Step 2. Printing `PRIVATE_KEY` only show the first line.
Change the variable to a single line. Like this:

```
PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\ndasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdadasdasdadasa\nhuehuauhhuauhahuauhauahuauhehuehuauheuhahue\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

If using the key inside an app 
e.g. node.
`process.env.PRIVATE_KEY` will be outputted correctly.

Answer (score 8):

I'll add that a more elegant fool-proof way is to encode the env var as base64 and then decode it when you access it.

```js
const base64 = process.env.GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY
const privateKey = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64')
```

Comment: Nail it! That works like a charm. I use in NestJS to get from the configModule and it was what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: fwiw AWS Lambda has a limit on env vars and the private key will likely be too long if base64 encoded